# Aperture to automatically import videos

Tags: video, aperture, import

Is it possible to have Aperture import videos alongside pictures when importing from a phone. It can handle videos, but when it shows me the list of things to import, only pictures are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Aperture 3.2.2 imports video and stills by default for me from my iPhone with iOS 5.0.1. Are you perhaps using older software or different hardware?

The only time I've seen Aperture not show items for import is when you take more photos / videos after the import window is open and the new captures will not show until you disconnect and reconnect the USB 30 pin connector.

Comment: As far as I know I'm using the latest version (at least, I never skipped any updates, but I'm going to check when I get home), but I'm not using an iPhone, I'm using an HTC Desire.

Answer (score 1):

You may have video files disabled in the import options.

- Open Aperture and click `Import`
- Click `Import Settings` on the right, and make sure `File Types` is checked in the list to show the File Types options.
- Under the File Types options, make sure `Exclude videos` is not checked.

If these options are set properly, connect the phone, locate the video files in the Finder, and verify they're playable by Quicktime player and/or the Finder (via Quick Look).  You can also try importing the file directly, by dragging it onto Aperture's dock icon.

If you can't view the video via Quicktime Player or Quick Look, try installing Perian and rebooting, but I'd be surprised if this is the case; most Android phones record in standard formats.

**Update**: Missing Sync reportedly correctly synchronizes Android videos, according to someone with the same phone as you http://androidforums.com/htc-desire/79684-htc-desire-mac.html

This is more of an alternative, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The settings were correct, videos are not being excluded. They are playable and I actually import them like you said, but since it's a manual separate process I tend to forget and it gets messy.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a report that Missing Sync does what you want.  Can you confirm?